# CouchDB: unable to create database with specific name: "no response"

Tags: curl, couchdb, pouchdb, couchdb-futon

I use a couch database and I can't create a new db with the name "ad". All the other names I tried don't make any problem. I tried with a smileupps server and with a iriscouch server and the problem is the same (but no problem in local).

I have a "no response" error message in Futon.

[image]

However, I can create the database with curl:

```
curl -X PUT https://couch-speech.smileupps.com/ad
```

Or even create and get documents...

But after that I can't use it in Futon (or Fauxton):

[image]

When I tried to open it I received this message:

> Error: An error occurred retrieving a list of all documents
>
> no response

When I try to call documents from internet (I use PouchDB), I have this error message:

> OPTIONS https://couch-speech.smileupps.com/ad/?_nonce=1443776580493
>   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT